# Vlookup or Match by split function

Tags: indexing, split, match, vlookup

I am working on a project in google sheets and I have tried to use INDEX, MATCH, SPLIT function to get the result in column B. It doesn't seems to work at all.
I have provided a screenshot below.

[Match & Split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEBJ3.png)

Column B is where it need to return the value from column D (Date) by matching in Column F (Desc.)
by separating the value of Column F by ","

The end result is shown below.

[Match & Split1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dVcb.png)

If anyone can help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula:

```
=QUERY($D$3:$F,"Select D where F like '%"&A3&"%'")
```